# can someone helps me understand why grep takes so long to go over /etc directory?

Tags: grep

So this is my code:

```
grep -l /etc
```

And it seems to still go through the file while I am typing. Maybe I midsunderstood what grep-l does?
[image]

Comment: Please add what you wanted to happen as a result of this command. And the version of grep being used will also help.

Comment: Please post text as text. Images of text have accessibility problems: i.e. hard to read, and near impossible to read by blind people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short help for grep (`grep --help`) shows:

```
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
```

Your command, `grep -l /etc` has the option `-l` and a pattern `/etc` but no file. It is waiting for you to type lines on your keyboard. (Normally you would use this form with a pipe from another command, e.g. `ls -l |grep one`.)

I think what you intended to write was:

```
grep -l -r search_pattern /etc
```

The `-l` (or `--files-with-matches`) option will "Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed. The scanning will stop on the first match."

The `-r` (or `--recursive`) option will "Read all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic links only if they are on the command line. Note that if no file operand is given, grep searches the working directory." User414777 says that this is "non-standard, but supported on BSD and MacOS too".

Quoted text is from the man page of GNU grep 3.4.

Comment: Linux or Mac is not the difference it is the version of `grep` that matters. You you mean on Gnu it is the same as `--files-with-matches`? There is more than one `grep` for both Mac and Linux.

Comment: The `-l` option of grep is standard (you can safely delete that Update: digression). It's `-r` (recursive) which is non-standard, but supported on BSD and MacOS too.

Comment: @user414777 - thank you; I have edit the answer accordingly